# Relevance of order of model construction in CP-SAT

Tags: or-tools, cp-sat

**Question 1:** Is ortool's CP-SAT sensitive to the order in which a model is constructed?

In other words, does it matter which variables and constraints come first?

I am seeing a high performance variance for some models which, unless I messed up, should be "the same" (isomorphic), and wonder if this should all be attributed to the non-determinism and heuristics in CP-SAT, or whether I could improve things by "normalizing" my model construction somehow.

**Question 2:** If so, are there best practices on which variables/constraints to list first?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a well know behavior of all MIP/CP solvers. Presolve and search are heavily heuristics based (to limit the complexity of the underlying algorithms), and thus are dependent on variables and constraints orders

The impact is known to be very large. And there is no way to define a canonical order.

See https://pubsonline.informs.org/doi/pdf/10.1287/educ.2013.0112

Comment: Thank you Laurent. What about rules of thumb that CP-user can apply to adjust the order in which they supply variables and constraints? I'm not looking for a hard formal rule -- otherwise I assume it would be automated and implemented -- but something informal that helps me make the right choices based on the intuition I have for the problem at hand. E.g. "Identify what is [or what you believe to be] the hardest part of the model, and name that first ..." or similar.

Comment: Not clear. Try to have variable that are close semantically be created around the same time. For constraints, the impact is less clear.

Comment: is it possible to provide an example showing how different orders change the performance ?

Comment: I have added a link to the original work.

Comment: Thanks @LaurentPerron!